# Screenshot not working in android

Tags: android, bitmap, screenshot

Here is my code.I want to take screenshot when button is clicked and preview the image in iamgeview and store in sd card.But when the button is clicked nothing happens!!Iam new to androdi.plz help!thanks in advance

```
case R.id.screnshotid:
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.Flayout);// get ur root view id
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    try {
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Bitmap bitmap;
  View v1 = findViewById(R.id.rlid);// get ur root view id
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
  v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

For saving

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
  File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "test.jpg")
  f.createNewFile();
  FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
  fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
  fo.close();
```

**Edit**

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            imageView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();

            OutputStream fOut = null;
            Uri outputFileUri;
            try {
                File root = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "folder_name" + File.separator);
                root.mkdirs();
                File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });
```

Don't forget to add permissions or it wont work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

By default it will save image inside your SDcard's folder and folder name is `folder_name` with `test.jpg` name.

Comment: Just put this code inside button's click event and give a try. Let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: Can u plz tel me wat are all the changes iam supposed to do..!! Iam new to android.I could not understand this bitmap concept much! @InnocentKiller

Comment: Just copy and paste this code inside your button's click event. That's it. Nothing more.

Comment: </activity>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>

Comment: Have added this at the end of my manifest file!!Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is absolutely fine, No problem at all.

Comment: Check inside your SDcard whether file with name `test.jpg` is exist or not.

Comment: No image is there in the sd card

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Flayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

Comment: i added the root as   View v1 = findViewById(R.id.Flayout);

Comment: your activity's xml file id is `Flayout`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Flayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

Comment: My root is framelayout and i have gievn id as Flayout!!

Comment: Can you show me code where exactly and how you have used this above code.

Comment: Have edited my code!!

Comment: @anusha, check my edit, try with that code, that is perfectly working code for me. It should work for you too.

Comment: what is this imageview.builddrawingcache? Its showing error like create local variable

Comment: The above second code will take the screenshot of particular imageview. it is not for entire screen.

Comment: ImageView imgshot;      imgshot.buildDrawingCache();
             Bitmap bm = imgshot.getDrawingCache();

Comment: My imageview name is imgshot so i used like this.Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, just replace `imageView` with `imgshot` and give a try.

Comment: Its not working.I have animation in  background.I think pblm is cz of  tat?

Comment: Just try this second code on simple imageview and check whether it is working or not.